# How to handle voice command intent via bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver, android-launcher

I need to open my own app when phone is connected to car bluetooth and media/speak button of car is pressed.
Currently when I press car media button it open google assistant, I need to bypass google assistant and open my app.

There is one app available called [bluetooth launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kin.bluetooth_launch)

which helps to open my app on media button pressed.

manifest of this app looks something like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".start_voice">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".config_voice">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I need to know how this app respond to media button as in this app no broadcast receiver is defined, Which things need to add in my code so it respond to car media button.

Any link or example is most welcome.